# How to pass a comparator a-la std::less to C-style Qsort?

Tags: c++, lambda, compare, qsort

So, I had an assignment to write a program to test speeds of different sorting algorithms, and one of them is good old `qsort`. I need to pass a comparator to it, but not the one it expects, but something boolean a-la `std::less`, and I know that to use it so that qsort accepts it, I need to actually pass it something like `less(b, a) - less(a,b)` --- this way, it has the range of `[-1; 1]` and produces what I need.

The problem is this: I have no idea how to actually do it! I tried to use lambda --- and (because I need to capture the comparator and qsort can't handle this) it failed. I tried to create another function converting my comparator to `qsort`'s:

```
int make_comparator(const void* a, const void* b) {
    return (int)comp(*(int*)b, *(int*)a) - (int)comp(*(int*)a, *(int*)b);
}
```

But I have no idea on how to actually pass the `comp` to it (because i can't just write `qsort(..., make_comparator(comp, a, b))`, can I?). I tried to use a template to pass `comp`, but couldn't figure out how.

So I'm struggling with it for like an hour already, and I'm no closer to a solution. What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: You either have to use a non-capturing lambda or a plain pointer to a **non**-member function, that's it.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, non-capturing lambda is unable to use `comp` parameter passed into my function, which, in turn, uses `qsort`, so that's not the option. 

Non-member function is also not an option, because, likewise, I can't think of a way to pass my `comp` to it.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Lookup `qsort_r`. Not standard, but the description will tell you more about what you want to do.

Comment: In your case, do you really need to specify comp at runtime, can't you define one "comparator" for each comp function, and just pass that to qsort?

Comment: @MarcGlisse, unfortunately, it's possible that I will actually need to choose in runtime, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this.  qsort_friendly_comparator just acts a wrapper around the comparator object.  The only downside is that you have to manually specify the comparator type and its argument type.

```
#include <functional>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>

// Assumes Comparator take two arguments of the same type and returns a bool.
// Have to manually specify the ArgType because it is tricky to deduce without
// excessive template magic.
template <typename Comparator, typename ArgType>
int qsort_friendly_comparator(const void *first, const void *second)
{
  Comparator comp;

  return (int)comp(*(ArgType*)second, *(ArgType*)first) -
         (int)comp(*(ArgType*)first,  *(ArgType*)second);
}

int main() {
  int data[] = {2, 1, 3, 0}; 

  qsort(data,
        /*num_elem=*/4,
        /*size_of_elem=*/sizeof(int),
        &qsort_friendly_comparator<std::less<int>, int>);

  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    printf("%d ", data[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Wow, that's amazing! I can't believe it was that easy. I'll try it and if everything works I'll accept this

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass `cmp` to `make_comparator` via `qsort`. Your best option is to have a function pointer that is set to the right function.

```
bool (*comp)(int a, int b) = nullptr;

int make_comparator(const void* a, const void* b) {
    return (int)comp(*(int*)b, *(int*)a) - (int)comp(*(int*)a, *(int*)b);
}
```

and later set `comp` to a valid function pointer

```
comp = <some function pointer>;
```

before calling `qsort`.

```
qsort(ptr, count, size, make_comparator);
```

If you choose to follow this approach, make sure to add checks in `make_comparator` to prevent calling `cmp` when it is not set to a valid function.

```
int make_comparator(const void* a, const void* b) {
    if ( comp == nullptr )
    {
       // Deal with error
    }
    return (int)comp(*(int*)b, *(int*)a) - (int)comp(*(int*)a, *(int*)b);
}
```

Comment: And what do I need to do to `bool (*comp)(int a, int b) = nullptr; ` to be able to compare any type, not only `int`? Can I use a template for that?

Comment: @Akiiino, If you want to use a template, you might as well use `std::less`. Then, there is no need to have `comp` at all.